# How to fix a Start button on the mini Javascript game?

Tags: javascript

My JS Game is Catch a Monster. However, I have problem with Start button. I have already put the Play Again button with location:reload(). I want the Start button pressed and the time starts counting down.

Now the time starts automatically every time page loads.

```js
function loadImages() {

  bgImage = new Image();

  bgImage.onload = function() {

    bgReady = true;

  };

  bgImage.src = "images/new-bgimage.jpg";

  heroImage = new Image();

  heroImage.onload = function() {

    heroReady = true;

  };

  heroImage.src = "images/new-superman.png";

  monsterImage = new Image();

  monsterImage.onload = function() {

    monsterReady = true;

  };

  monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";
}


// KEYBOARD


function setupKeyboardListeners() {

  addEventListener("keydown", function(key) {

    keysDown[key.keyCode] = true;

  }, false);

  addEventListener("keyup", function(key) {

    delete keysDown[key.keyCode];

  }, false);
}


// SET UP START BUTTON

let myVar;

function setBegin() {

  myVar = setTimeout(update(), 3000);
}




let update = function() {

  elapsedTime = Math.floor((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);

  if (elapsedTime >= SECONDS_PER_ROUND) {

    return;
  }
  keySet() //moving the hero character

  heroMoveOffScreen() //moving the hero character

  ifCatchMonster() //moving the monster character randomly when catch
};




var main = function() {

  render();

  requestAnimationFrame(main);

  setBegin();
};



// RUN THE GAME


loadImages()

setupKeyboardListeners()

main()
```

```html
<button id="startGame" value="Start" onclick="setBegin()">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setBegin()` from the `main()` function:

```
var main = function () {

  render();

  requestAnimationFrame(main); 

  //setBegin(); ( Don't start immediately)
};
```